# For this matrix $A$, what is $A^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & a & b \\ 0& 0 & c \\ 0& 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$$

What is $A^n$ (for $n\geq 1)$?

Comment: Have you calculated $A^2$?

Comment: Well, I am certain you can handle the case n=2.

Comment: Yes I have, but not the general case for A^n.

Comment: @Leslie Now try $A^3$; what can you say?

Comment: It's the zero matrix then right?

Comment: And what can you say about multiplying a matrix with the  zero matrix?

Comment: But for n≥1, I don't know how to phrase the general solution for A^n.

Comment: @Leslie look at the answer

Comment: Since $A^3 = 0, A^4 = 0 ... A^n = 0$, i.e., for all $n>2 \implies A^n = 0$

Comment: Oh right.Thanks! My all-nighter is getting to me...

Comment: Got it? :-)  You know more than you think you do!

Comment: In posts like this, it would have helped from the start to say that you know $A^2$, and that $A^3 = 0$...but that you are confused about how, exactly, to state the general case. Then people don't bother you by telling you what you know...the more you let us know where you're stuck, the more quickly we can help ;-)

Comment: True true.. I will definitely do that for the next problem I'm stuck on!!

Answer (score 5):

This matrix is a nilpotent one, so we know that $A^3=0$. Now we calculate 
$$A^2=A\cdot A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0& c \\0  & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0& c \\0  & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & ac \\ 0 & 0& 0 \\0  & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
As $A^3=0$ $A^n=0$ for $n>2$

Instead of using that every strict upper triagle matrix is nilpotent we could calculate $A^3$
$$A^3 = A \cdot A^2= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0& c \\0  & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & ac \\ 0 & 0& 0 \\0  & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0& 0 \\0  & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Beat me to it by 12 seconds.

Comment: "This matrix is a nilpotent one..."

That's putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: @Rhys i added the calculation